# DevExpress Reporting: prevent text label field (and the entire detail record) from being split over more than one page

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

Is there a built-in way to move the detail row, in its entirety, to the next page when a multi-line label in the detail section would have its contents split across a page break?

For example, preventing this:

```
               TITLE                                              STARRING

               .
               .
               .
               .

               Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless                   Kate Winslet, Jim Carrey
               [page-break]---------------------------------------------------------------

               Mind
```

and having this instead:

```
              [page-break]----------------------------------------------------------------
              TITLE                                              STARRING                        
              Eternal Sunshine of the Spotless                   Kate Winslet, Jim Carrey
              Mind
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

`Keep Together` property of the Detail band.